# ¿Por qué me cambia el índice en mi array de php?

Tags: php, array

Estoy trabajando en PHP y creando arrays con key enteras muy grandes, en linux me funciona pero en windows no.

No he podido encontrar la solución, ni si quiera aumentando el ini_set.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ejemplo:

```
 key = 104360000114250 // este es el original que lo asigno al array como clave

[2147483647] => Array  // así me lo castea cuando lo instancio
    (
        [id] => 104360000114250
        [Cantidad] =>  1
    )
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, lee el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender como funciona el sitio y [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Añade el código que has intentado y el porqué no te funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Podrias colcoar tu codigo porfavor?

Comment: Te da algún tipo de error o simplemente no funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ser claves de tipo integer o entero nos tenemos que ir a ver los límites de estos, en el manual podemos encontrar lo siguiente:

> El tamaño de un integer depende de la plataforma, aunque el valor
>   usual es un valor máximo de aproximadamente dos mil millones (esto es,
>   32 bits con signo). Las plataformas de 64 bits normalmente tienen un
>   valor máximo de aproximadamente 9E18, excepto en Windows antes de PHP
>   7, que siempre es de 32 bits. PHP no tiene soporte para el tipo
>   integer sin signo. El tamaño de un integer se puede determinar
>   mediante la constante PHP_INT_SIZE, y el valor máximo mediante la
>   constante PHP_INT_MAX desde PHP 4.4.0 y PHP 5.0.5, y el valor mínimo
>   mediante la constante PHP_INT_MIN desde PHP 7.0.0.

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.integer.php

Para evitar esto puedes utilizar las claves como String en lugar de enteros.

```
$key = "104360000114250";

[$key] => Array
    (
        [id] => 104360000114250
        [Cantidad] =>  1
    )
```

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en la arquitectura, 32 y 64 bits.
En 64 bits me funciona (linux), pero en windows (tengo 64 bits) pero xampp SOLO VIENE en 32bits (86x) y por eso creo que no me deja ingresar más dígitos al índice.
He buscado como cambiar el xampp (o php precisamente) de 32 a 64 pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: Según el manual la versiones x64 de PHP **<** 7 para windows  son experimentales, y no se recomiendan. http://php.net/manual/es/install.windows.manual.php